# What is missing from this sequence of words?

Tags: word-sequence

What is missing from this sequence?

> SUM, SUN, SIX, -, SIP

*Source: GCHQ Puzzle book*

Comment: Nice puzzle... curious to see some answers. I'm stumped!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My answer is:

> SNORCIMO

Explaination:

> The word sequence given contains in order the 12th (Mu), 13th (Nu), 14th (Xi), and 16th (Pi) letters of the Greek alphabet reversed with an added "S". The missing Greek letter in the order is the 15th letter of the alphabet (Omicron). Following the same naming convention gives you SNORCIMO:
>
>
>  Mu = SUM
>  Nu = SUN
>  Xi = SIX
>  Omicron = SNORCIMO
>  Pi = SIP

Comment: Very nicely done! How did you spot it?

Comment: Well, I was trying to find a pattern for a while. When nothing was working I flipped the words backwards and the Greek letter just popped out at me! Great puzzle, I had a lot of fun even though it drove me crazy for a bit 

Comment: Sorry, it's not a word.